# Add tooltip in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, tooltip

I'm trying to implement a tooltip for a DlgItem and it is not working, no text is showing.
I tried with this function :

```
HWND CreateToolTip(int toolID, HWND hDlg, PTSTR pszText)
{
    if (!toolID || !hDlg || !pszText)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Get the window of the tool.
    HWND hwndTool = GetDlgItem(hDlg, toolID);


    // Create the tooltip. g_hInst is the global instance handle.
    HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        hDlg, NULL,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    if (!hwndTool || !hwndTip)
    {
        return (HWND)NULL;
    }

    // Associate the tooltip with the tool.
    TOOLINFO toolInfo = { 0 };
    toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
    toolInfo.hwnd = hDlg;
    toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hwndTool;
    toolInfo.lpszText = pszText;
    SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo);

    return hwndTip;
}
```

And I call this function like this :

```
CreateToolTip(ITEM_ID, this->m_hWnd, L"MY_TEXT");
```

But the tooltip isn't here.

Do you have any ideas ?
Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: `return FALSE;` is an unusual statement in a function that returns a value of type `HWND`. Regardless, what insights did you gather from stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: @IInspectable I used the Microsoft function from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-tooltip-for-a-control. And I can't use the debugger because the project only runs in release mode that's why it's difficult for me

Comment: Debug your release configuration then. You can instruct your compiler to generate debug symbols regardless of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this code to work normally, I think you did not generate the manifest file, causing the `SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo);` call to fail.

If you are using Visual Studio, go to project properties:

**Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Manifest -> Generate Manifest file: Yes**

Then add the list style, refer to [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview):

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Finally it worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.